# ¿Como pasar tuplas como argumentos de una función? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuplas

Tengo una función a la que le quiero pasar **cuatro** argumentos en total (ar,ai,br,bi). Hasta el momento le paso los argumentos así:

```
def subt(ar,ai,br,bi):
```

Me funciona bien, ya que la función me retorna los resultados esperados, pero quiero pasar los argumentos en dos tuplas, algo así:

```
def subt((ar,ai),(br,bi)):
```

Cuando ejecuto la función de esta manera (la manera anterior) me da este error:

```
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\name.py", line 1
    def add((ar,ai),(br,bi)):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Investigando, me dí cuenta que con algo como `x: tuple` como parámetro puedo pasar una tupla, ahí surge otra pregunta como le puedo especificar que la tupla es dos elementos y esos dos elementos son enteros? Además se me dificulataría manejar los argumentos ya que la función está construida así:

```
def subt(ar,ai,br,bi):
    i = 1
    ai = ai * i
    bi = bi * i

    print(f"({ar - br} + {ai - bi}i)")
```

Entonces no sé como pasarle los cuatro argumentos en dos tuplas, el resultado que deseo es que la invocación sea coomo esto:

```
subt((3,4),(4,3))
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tú mismo has dicho, la función ha de recibir dos tuplas, por tanto **dos parámetros**. Es decir, su cabecera deberá ser:

```
def subt(tupla1, tupla2):
   ...
```

Y por tanto la invocación `subt((3,4),(4,3))` ya funcionará, y la función recibirá en su primer parámetro la tupla `(3,4)` y en el segundo la tupla  `(4,3)`.

Si quieres, para que el cuerpo de la función quede similar a lo que tenías escrito, puedes *desempaquetar* las tuplas una vez recibidas. Con ello tu función quedaría así:

```
def subt(tupla1, tupla2):
    ar, ai = tupla1
    br, b1 = tupla2
    i = 1
    ai = ai * i
    bi = bi * i

    print(f"({ar - br} + {ai - bi}i)")
```

El desempaquetado se realiza en las dos primeras líneas de la función y consiste en asignar la tupla recibida a dos variables. Funcionará siempre que la tupla recibida tenga efectivamente dos valores.

### Con tipos

Si quieres declarar los tipos que se están usando, en este caso sería así:

```
from typing import Tuple

def subt(tupla1: Tuple[int, int], tupla2: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
    ar, ai = tupla1
    br, b1 = tupla2
    i = 1
    ai = ai * i
    bi = bi * i

    print(f"({ar - br} + {ai - bi}i)")
```

El tipo `Tuple[int, int]` significa exactamente lo que querías: una tupla con dos elementos, ambos de tipo `int`.

Answer (score 1):

La función está definida para 4 argumentos. Si quieres usarla con dos tuplas, la solución es crear función auxiliar que adapte unos argumentos en otros:

```py
def subt2(tupla1: Tuple[int, int], tupla2: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
    return subt(tupla1[0], tupla1[1], tupla2[0], tupla2[1])
```

De todos modos, python no te garantiza que esta función sólo se invoque con tuplas de dos elementos, aunque así lo pongas en el tipado de los argumentos. El tipado sólo es informativo, no restrictivo.

```
In [10]: subt2((1,2),(3,))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b98c87a5de01> in <module>
----> 1 subt2((1,2),(3,))

<ipython-input-8-3c2797310102> in subt2(tupla1, tupla2)
      1 def subt2(tupla1: Tuple[int, int], tupla2: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
----> 2     return subt(tupla1[0], tupla1[1], tupla2[0], tupla2[1])

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Si no quieres crear una nueva función, también puedes usar la inyección de los elementos de una secuencia en la llamada de la función con la indicación `*` delante. Algo así:

```py
x = (3,4)
y = (4,3)
subt(*x, *y)
```

No es la mejor solución, pero puede servir. Igualmente, no se comprueba el número de elementos que tiene cada tupla. Deberías añadir código que haga la comprobación para evitar que se propagen los errores.

PD: por si no lo sabías, en python existe el tipo [`complex`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). Estas operaciones de tuplas parecen de cálculo complejo. Usando *complex* como tipo de dato puede ser más seguro que trabajar con tuplas.